# I have multiple layouts but how can i select only one of the layout out of those(like a quiz option)

Tags: android, android-layout

i have multiple layout out of which i can opt only one like in a quiz application option selection,how can i achievve this without using radio  groups.
The layout i used is linear layout .

```
holder.layexcellent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.round_exc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectround);



                }

            });

                holder.layverygood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.round_vgood.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectround);
                    }
                });


                holder.laygood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.round_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectround);
                 }
                });


        holder.laysatifactory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.round_sat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectround);

            }
        });
        holder.laypoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.round_poor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectround);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way u can solve the problem,if u r not using radiogroups.

```
         holder.layexcellent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
               {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

              holder.layverygood.setClickable(false);
              holder.laygood.setClickable(false);
              holder.laysatifactory.setClickable(false);
              holder.laypoor.setClickable(false);

                }

            });
```